# Passing dynamic model to partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an option for user to select the reporting view between 2 date range.

Below is my **ReportsViewModel.cs**

```
public class ReportsViewModel
{
    public DateTime DateRangeFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateRangeTo { get; set; }
    public string ReportFor { get; set; }
    public SelectList ReportForList { get; set; }
}
```

Now `ReportForList` will have values like **Any**,**Table1**,**Table2**,**Table3**.

If user selects **Any** the `model` that is going to get generated will be from all the 3 tables and so and hence the structure of the model will be based on user selection. How would I go generating `model` for this and pass it into `PartialView`? Will it be a set of `Key/Value` pairs or should `dynamic` be used here? Is there anyway to achieve the reporting structure for above requirement?

Comment: If the models are different, why not different partials for each model?

Comment: Like 4 different partial views? @StephenMuecke

Comment: Yes, and in the controller method - `if (ReportFor = "Any") { var model = ...; return PartialView("_AnyReport, model);) else if (ReportFor = "Table1") { var model = ...; return PartialView("_Table1Report", model);) etc` (but suggest you use a enum for the `ReportFor` values)

Comment: Oh.. Alright @StephenMuecke.. Will go that way.. But there isn't anyway to make use of `dynamic` here right?

Comment: Far better to strongly type your view to a model (and assuming there will be common properties, then each model can derive for a base model)

Comment: @StephenMuecke.. Getting some idea with your last comment but its blurred little bit on my vision. Could you please provide dummy sample as an answer, if you don't mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, avoid using `dynamic`. You lose compile-time checking, intellisense and the ability to use the `***For()` methods in your view (lambda expressions do not support dynamic objects).

Instead use strong types and create a view model for each report. Assuming there will be some common properties, then start with a base model

```
public abstract class ReportBase
{
    .... // common properties
}
public class Report1 : ReportBase
{
    .... // properties specific table 1
}
public class Report2 : ReportBase
{
    .... // properties specific table 2
}
```

and then create strong typed partial views for each model, for example `_Report1.cshtml`

```
@model Report1 // or IEnumerable<Report1>
```

and in the controller method

```
public PartialViewResult ShowReport(ReportsViewModel model)
{
    if (model.ReportFor == "Table1")
    {
        Report1 report = .... // your query to generate data
        return PartialView("_Report1", report);
    }
    else if (model.ReportFor == "Table2")
    {
        Report2 report = .... // your query to generate data
        return PartialView("_Report2", report);
    }
    else if (....
```